# Fatal error: Can't use method return value in write context in

Tags: php

I am trying to make a small survey form asking people questions and replying either yes or no.

I am trying though to execute the the first two functions on the 3rd function and also check if the answers were set but i get a:

> Fatal error: Can't use method return value in write context in.

Can someone please help me or point me to the right path?

```
    <?php
class survey {

    ... some functions ...

    function check($rep1, $rep2){

        if (isset($this->q1($rep1)) && isset($this->q2($rep2))) {
            #######################    #######################
            echo "Thank you for the feedback";
        }elseif (! array_key_exists(@$_POST['answer'], $var)) {
            echo "Please select an option<br/>";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

The error is inside the check function on the first line.

Comment: [The Definitive Guide To PHP's isset And empty](http://kunststube.net/isset/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since functions always return *something* (even if it's `NULL`), using `isset()` on them is nonsensical.

`isset` is a language construct that takes a variable name and tells you if it exists.

In this case, why not just write `if(isset($_POST['answer']))`?

Comment: Thank you Kolink. You have been very helpful. The only thing is that I need to run the q1 and q2 functions only when the questions have been answered.. any ideas how this can be done? Thanks again for helping a newbie out..

Comment: @Kolink Shouldn't isset of a variable which exists but is set to `null` return false?

Comment: @Panki0: This is possible without errors in PHP 5.5. All you need to do is to upgrade to that PHP version. It's currently available in a alpha or beta release, so you can already test it today. http://php.net/

Comment: @igorpan: yes. isset, basically checks for NULL not whether or not a variable is set.

Comment: I have fixed it it guys. Thank you all for trying to help out! I really appreciate it! Just thinking opposite/reverse actually made the script work. Thanks a lot again.